# How can I stop a running operation in the SLIME REPL?

Tags: emacs, clojure, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, slime

Is there a way to stop a running operation in the SLIME REPL?

The Clojure SLIME folks [apparently have some way to do this](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/e05cc5a9c1dc8b1), so how about in ordinary Common Lisp?

Thanks /Erik

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As expected, it turns out it was quite simple. To stop a running operation use the command `slime-interrupt` (C-c C-b).

Comment: `C-c C-c` is wrong! It compiles the last expression. `C-c C-b` is `M-x slime-interrupt`.